# Vim: Limit upwards search by one directory

Tags: file, search, vim, find

I have the following file structure:

```
.
├── main
└── src
    └── main.c
```

If I'm editing the file `main.c` and use the command

```
:echo findfile(expand('%:t:r'),";")
```

Vim prints `main`. But if `main` does not exist then `findfile` will keep searching upwards until the root directory `/` and that can take a long time.

Is there a way to limit the [upward search ";"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching) to one directory? I'm looking for something similar to `**2` which sets the maximum downward search level to 2.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot limit the upward search to one directory, you can instead specify the starting path to be up one directory relative to where you are now and then search downward only a directory:

```
:echo findfile(expand('%:t:r'),"../**1")
```

This works well for the sample question. Higher upward directories (`../../../../**4`) would become tedious to specify, and would have the detriment of searching in the opposite order (top-down rather than bottom-up), though I'm not sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the upward search level to one I ended up using `expand('%:p:h')`:

```
execute "echo findfile(expand('%:t:r'),';".expand('%:p:h')."')"
```

or use `getcwd`:

```
execute "echo findfile(expand('%:t:r'),';".getcwd()."')"
```